# the huge difference of two different implementation for the same model

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am using two different ways to implement the same type of model,

**Method 1**

```python
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
optimizer = 'Adagrad'
batch_size = 256
nr_of_epochs = 80

model= Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(60,32, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal',input_shape=(64,1)))
model.add(Conv1D(80,10, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(Conv1D(100,5, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dense(300,activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse','mae'])
history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_val,Y_val), shuffle=True, epochs=nr_of_epochs,verbose=2)
```

**Method 2**

```python
inputs = Input(shape=(64,1))
outX = Conv1D(60, 32, strides=1, activation='relu',padding='causal')(inputs)
outX = Conv1D(80, 10, activation='relu',padding='causal')(outX)
outX = Conv1D(100, 5, activation='relu',padding='causal')(outX)
outX = MaxPooling1D(2)(outX)
outX = Dense(300, activation='relu')(outX)
outX = Flatten()(outX)
predictions = Dense(1,activation='linear')(outX)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs],outputs=predictions)
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss=loss_function, optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['mse','mae'])
history=model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_val,Y_val), shuffle=True,epochs=nr_of_epochs,verbose=2)
```

The model architecture of both methods should be the same, please see the following images

**Method 1**

[image]

**Method 2**

[image]

Even their architecture are kind of the same, but the training process are very different when I feed them into exactly the same data set. In the first implementation, the loss function stop decreasing just after one epoch; while the second implementation has a reasonable training loss converging trend. Why it has such a larger difference?

**Method 1**

```python
625s - loss: 0.0670 - mean_squared_error: 0.0670 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0647 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 2/120                                                                                                                                        
624s - loss: 0.0647 - mean_squared_error: 0.0647 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0641 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 3/120                                                                                                                                        
624s - loss: 0.0647 - mean_squared_error: 0.0647 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0641 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 4/120                                                                                                                                        
625s - loss: 0.0647 - mean_squared_error: 0.0647 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0641 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 5/120                                                                                                                                        
624s - loss: 0.0647 - mean_squared_error: 0.0647 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0641 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 6/120                                                                                                                                        
622s - loss: 0.0647 - mean_squared_error: 0.0647 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0641 - val_loss: 0.0653 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0653 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0646
```

**Method 2**

```python
429s - loss: 0.0623 - mean_squared_error: 0.0623 - mean_absolute_error: 0.1013 - val_loss: 0.0505 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0505 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.1006                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 2/80                                                                                                                                         
429s - loss: 0.0507 - mean_squared_error: 0.0507 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0977 - val_loss: 0.0504 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0504 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0988                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 3/80                                                                                                                                         
429s - loss: 0.0503 - mean_squared_error: 0.0503 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0964 - val_loss: 0.0498 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0498 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0954                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 4/80                                                                                                                                         
428s - loss: 0.0501 - mean_squared_error: 0.0501 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0955 - val_loss: 0.0498 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0498 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0962                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 5/80                                                                                                                                         
429s - loss: 0.0499 - mean_squared_error: 0.0499 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0951 - val_loss: 0.0501 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0501 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0960                                                                                                                                  
Epoch 6/80                                                                                                                                         
430s - loss: 0.0498 - mean_squared_error: 0.0498 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0947 - val_loss: 0.0495 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0495 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0941
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activation in the last layer is different: `'relu'` x `'linear'`.

This alone produces results that are very different. (The relu one will never produce negative results).

Also, there is a lot of "luck" involved, especially when using "relu" in the entire model.

Weights in each model are initialized randomly, so they're not "the same" (unless you force the weights from one into another using `model.get_weights()` and `model.set_weights()`). And "relu" is an activation that must be used with care. Learning rates that are too big may quickly set all results to zero, stopping learning before the model has really learned anything.

---

Is this a binary classification model? If so, use "sigmoid" in the last layer.

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is a MLP model, the  output will be used for prediction, Besides, do you mean that we should change the last dense layer to sigmoid?

Comment: Are there any rules/guidances on using "ReLu"? Is "Linear" more robust?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but it may depend on your application. What I know is: "relu" is linear without negative values (it truncates negatuve values to zero, preventing backpropagation - constant values don't have a gradient). --- I myself never had good results with "relu", but judging by the amount of people using it, it probably has its merits, but must be used with compatible learning rates and weight initializations to avoid all zeros. Personally, I like 'tanh', it may not have the advantages of 'relu' (of which I'm not aware), but it certainly doesn't cause me trouble during training.

Comment: In the output layer, you must choose your activation based on your output data. In classifications, where values go from 0 to 1, use "sigmoid". If outputting real values, try finding maximum and minimum values and normalize the outputs to fit either a 'sigmoid' (0 to 1)  or a 'tanh' (-1 to +1).